# Create a custom title

Tags: titles

I have to create a report that contains:

- Date
- Group (number)
- Authors (two)
- Title
- Assistant name

What is the best way to do this with an article (`scrartcl`) in classicthesis? I need that all this stuff don't take a lot of space, but I want a good typographical result. I tried with `\\` on `\title{}` but I wasn't able to obtain a good result.

```
\documentclass[%
    10pt,%
    a4paper,%
    onside,%
    headinclude,%
    footinclude,%
    BCOR5mm,%
    captions=tableheading]%
        {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
    nochapters,%
    beramono,%
    eulermath,%
    pdfspacing,%
    listings]%
        {classicthesis}

\author{Authors}
\title{Title}
\date{Date}

% Where to put group number and assistant name??


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

EDIT: For example, if I use

```
\authors{myname \and otherautor \\ assistantname}
```

`assistantname` will be placed under `otherautor` and not centered on the page...

Comment: Can you please explain how do you mix two classes: `scrartcl` and `classicthesis`? I think a M(n)WE is needed here.

Comment: @tohecz `scrartcl` is the class, `classicthesis` is a package. What is a M(n)WE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at page 59 in the English manual, There you will find descriptions of different additional title commands.

For example, you can put the group number at the top of the page by using `\titlehead`, and the assistant’s name by using `\publishers`. If you want the assistant’s name centred under two author names, you can ‘cheat’ by using the the `\date`-command, *i.e.*:

```
\author{Author \and Author}
\date{\small Assistant: John Doe \\[2ex]%
      \large Date}
```

Here is a MWE, cheating with the `\date`-and `\publishers`:

```
\documentclass[%
    10pt,%
    a4paper,%
    onside,%
    headinclude,%
    footinclude,%
    BCOR5mm,%
    captions=tableheading]%
        {scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[%
    nochapters,%
    beramono,%
    eulermath,%
    pdfspacing,%
    listings]%
        {classicthesis}

\author{Author \and Author}
\title{Title}
\date{\small Group Number: SS~2002 \\[1ex] \large Date}
\publishers{\medskip\small Assistant: John Doe}
% Where to put group number and assistant name??


\begin{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The `publisher` is a good solution. I would like to place the group number under authors names (centered)... It is possible?

Comment: @R.M. See my updated MWE and example.